# How can a user undownvote posts after the votes are locked?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

Yesterday, some of [my questions were downvoted.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1369235/hims056?tab=reputation&StartDate=2013-08-20) But today, three of those downvoted questions were undownvoted. But [none](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10664790/1369235) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11466308/1369235) [them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11481269/1369235) were edited after the downvotes. My question is how can a user undownvote posts after the votes are locked?

Not sure whether it's related or not but my today's reputation on the top bar is [showing 0 instead of 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YagYX.png).

<sup>PS: I am not discussing anything about serial voting</sup>

Comment: Wow isn't there any tag like `undownvote` or `un-voting`?

Comment: that actually may be related to the votes of someone serially voting. I've seen votes invalidated in that way before, but never asked about the different appearance.

Comment: @Andrew - You mean this is a serial voting reversed with undownvote? or anything else?

Comment: it might be manual invalidation, or some particular means of removal separate from how the typical group-invalidation works. I've seen it before with someone I reported to staff for targeted voting.

Comment: Yeah, this happened to me too. I've been the victim of serial downvoting, then the next they the user "undownvoted" my posts. It was clearly the reversal.

Comment: @H2CO3 - Then the question is why only three votes were reversed? :)

Comment: Since it's a serial voting reversed I am talking about it. It's a duplicate. But now the question is why only three votes were reversed?

Comment: I am almost certain any answer to that question will be 'obfuscated' in the name of votes being anonymous and not wanting to reveal too much about vote-cheating systems. I have *no knowledge* of the specifics there, but one *wild* guess; a manual decision could have been made concerning which votes might have been made in 'good faith' or not. Now that I put that in words, it seems like a horrible suggestion, but, there it is! heh