# What can I do when not all serial downvotes seem to be reversed?

Tags: discussion, support, serial-voting

This is relevant to the question [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me).

I had the same thing happen to me yesterday, as six of my answers were downvoted at the same time.
According to the answers provided to the question above, I should get the reputation back.

However, it seems that while some of my reputation was returned, not all of it has been. (basically half of the lost reputation)

> [image]

Can I do anything about this?

Comment: Not really no. Then the system, with its detailed information, determined not all events were serial downvotes. Perhaps some of them were legitimate and just unfortunately timed.

Comment: Is it? but they were downvoted with in 2minutes window! except one

Comment: 5 of the downvotes were within 2 minutes and 3 have been reversed.

Comment: @huMptyduMpty Mere assumptions. We don't know and moderators don't know. You could flag for attention, or perhaps this post will be seen by a dev. But getting more of your rep back is unlikely I'd say.

Comment: @fedorqui: All those answers were already having 5 or 5+ votes! So what happned to the other two?

Comment: @Bart: How can I flag this kind of situation for moderator attention?

Comment: I guess there is a pattern that those 3 matched and the other 2 did not... As the algorithm is not known, it is difficult to guess what really happened.

Comment: @huMptyduMpty Flag one of the affected posts using the "other" option.

Comment: Yeah [happened to me too](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194085/how-can-a-user-undownvote-posts-after-the-votes-are-locked#comment609467_194085). Serially downvoted on [20 Aug](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1369235/hims056?tab=reputation&sort=post&StartDate=2013-08-20%2000:00:00Z&page=2) on 6 posts. But only 3 were reversed on [21 Aug](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1369235/hims056?tab=reputation&sort=post&StartDate=2013-08-20%2000:00:00Z&page=1).

Comment: @Bart - I did it but they didn't find any evidence to support it.

Comment: So then you know what my next bit of advice would be @hims056 .... ;)

Comment: @Bart - I did the same... *Move on*.. :P

Comment: I think it's two users. I've asked a community manager to look at it.

Comment: @Flexo: Seems something happned. I can see two of those questions with `undownvote` and reputation is given back. Thanks!!

Comment: Lol!!! It is just 12 downvotes... Not millions of money :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have flag one my question (which got downvoted) as `others - >needs moderator attention` (As suggest by Bart in one of the comment)

I received response from Stack Exchange Team after sometimes and they have un-down voted those down votes and reputation is back.